# I'm getting a error Function eregi()

Tags: php, regex

I'm getting a Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\website\Web_Intersect_v1.34\profile.php on line 231.
I try to use preg_match() and that dosn't work. What should I use to make the code work.

```
$OSList = array
(
    // Match user agent string with operating systems
    'Windows 3.11' => 'Win16',
    'Windows 95' => '(Windows 95)|(Win95)|(Windows_95)',
    'Windows 98' => '(Windows 98)|(Win98)',
    'Windows 2000' => '(Windows NT 5.0)|(Windows 2000)',
    'Windows XP' => '(Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP)',
    'Windows Server 2003' => '(Windows NT 5.2)',
    'Windows Vista' => '(Windows NT 6.0)',
    'Windows 7' => '(Windows NT 6.1)|(Windows NT 7.0)',
    'Windows NT 4.0' => '(Windows NT 4.0)|(WinNT4.0)|(WinNT)|(Windows NT)',
    'Windows ME' => 'Windows ME',
    'Open BSD' => 'OpenBSD',
    'Sun OS' => 'SunOS',
    'Linux' => '(Linux)|(X11)',
    'Mac OS' => '(Mac_PowerPC)|(Macintosh)',
    'QNX' => 'QNX',
    'BeOS' => 'BeOS',
    'OS/2' => 'OS/2',
    'Mac OS' => 'Mac OS',
    'Search Bot'=>'(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp)|(MSNBot)|(Ask Jeeves/Teoma)|(ia_archiver)'
);

// Loop through the array of user agents and matching operating systems
foreach($OSList as $CurrOS=>$Match) {
    // Find a match
    if (eregi($Match, $agent)) {
            break;
    } else {
        $CurrOS = "Unknown OS";
    }
}
$device = "$user_device : $CurrOS";
```

Comment: Error is clear. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php read big orange box

Comment: can you provide the value of `$agent`?

Comment: @atoms why does that matter??

Comment: @Dagon thought I could provide the regex for preg replace `preg_match('/pattern/i', ...);`

Comment: looking at it now i dont see how that will work anyway

Comment: @Dagon thanks for the link it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (preg_match("/iPhone/", $agent)) {
$user_device = "iPhone Mobile";
}   else if (preg_match("/Android/", $agent)) {
$user_device = "Android Mobile";
} else if (preg_match("/IEMobile/", $agent)) {
$user_device = "Windows Mobile";
} else if (preg_match("/Chrome/", $agent)) {
$user_device = "Google Chrome";
} else if (preg_match("/MSIE/", $agent)) {
$user_device = "Internet Explorer";
} else if (preg_match("/Firefox/", $agent)) {
$user_device = "Firefox";
} else if (preg_match("/Safari/", $agent)) {
$user_device = "Safari";
} else if (preg_match("/Opera/", $agent)) {
$user_device = "Opera";
}
```